# MySQL select where ID is IN (SELECT another table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

the problem is that I need to select values from table

```
category_filter_relations

id   modification_id
```

where my entered modification_id is equal to a variable and also I need to join another table

```
category_filter_relations_items

id   modification_id   category_filter_relation_id
```

where can be multiple entries with the same `modification_id` and different `category_filter_relation_id` and I need to select those `category_filter_relations` items.

My query:

```
SELECT cfr.id AS category_filter_relation_id, 
       cfr.modification_id,
FROM category_filter_relations cfr
WHERE 1
AND cfr.modification_id = '18340300'
AND category_filter_relation_id 
IN (SELECT category_filter_relations_items.category_filter_relation_id 
    FROM category_filter_relations_items 
    WHERE category_filter_relations_items.modification_id = '18340300')
```

And this way I get an error:

> Unknown column 'category_filter_relation_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Also I tried to join the

```
LEFT JOIN category_filter_relations_items ON (category_filter_relations_items.category_filter_relation_id = category_filter_relation_id)
```

but this way I get all the entries from `category_filter_relations_items`
 table and I need the entries from

```
category_filter_relations where category_filter_relations.modification_id = 18340300
```

joined with

```
category_filter_relations_items.category_filter_relation_id where category_filter_relations_items.modification_id = 18340300
```

Data example of what I need:

```
category_filter_relations
id    modification_id
23796 18340300

category_filter_relations_items 
id      category_filter_relation_id  modification_id     
54690   23270                        18340300
```

I am selecting the table category_filter_relations and the result should be:

```
id    modification_id
23796 18340300
23270 11111111
```

It took the id 23270 because category_filter_relations_items.modification_id was equal to 18340300

Comment: remove the comma here: `cfr.modification_id,
`

Comment: share table sample data and expected output

Comment: edited the main post with example data

Comment: Give aliases to your tables in the query. That way, you won't have to rewrite the table names for each attribute

Comment: Will do, it's just a fast example data, the whole table is bigger. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would `modification_id` = 11111111 if you are selecting for `cfr.modification_id = '18340300'` this is not making sense to me. Can you expand on the sample data so it is possible to produce that result?

Comment: The id 23270 has it's own modification_id (11111111) and it's connected via id (23270) to the table category_filter_relations where category_filter_relation_id is 23270. But it has modification_id 18340300 so we need to pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your tables :

```
category_filter_relations
=========================
id |  modification_id
```

and

```
category_filter_relations_items
===================================================
id | modification_id | category_filter_relation_id
```

In your query, you do :

```
SELECT cfr.id AS category_filter_relation_id, -- You select the category_filter_relations id
       cfr.modification_id,                   -- You select the modification_id
FROM category_filter_relations cfr            -- Both from the table category_filter_relations
WHERE 1
AND cfr.modification_id = '18340300'          -- You add a condition on the modification_id
AND category_filter_relation_id               -- You add a condition on an id not in the table category_filter_relations
IN (SELECT category_filter_relations_items.category_filter_relation_id 
    FROM category_filter_relations_items 
    WHERE category_filter_relations_items.modification_id = '18340300')
```

The output you want is :

```
id    modification_id
23796 18340300
23270 11111111
```

How is this possible if you add a condition `AND cfr.modification_id = '18340300'` ?
You can't get `modification_id = 11111111` if you only ask for `modification_id = '18340300'`.

So try this maybe :

```
SELECT cfr.id, 
       cfr.modification_id,
FROM category_filter_relations cfr
WHERE cfr.modification_id = '18340300'

UNION

SELECT cfri.id, 
       cfri.modification_id,
FROM category_filter_relations_items cfri
INNER JOIN category_filter_relations cfr ON cfr.id = cfri.category_filter_relation_id
    AND cfr.modification_id = '18340300'
```

This way you get the first row from `category_filter_relations` with column name `id` (the `id` of `category_filter_relations`) and `modification_id` (the `modification_id` of `category_filter_relations`) which is equal to '18340300' because of the condition.

The `UNION` now will have the column `id` too but now it's the `id` of the table `category_filter_relations_items` and a column `modification_id` that will be the `modification_id` of the row of `category_filter_relations_items` where `category_filter_relation_id` is the `id` of the table `category_filter_relations` which have `modification_id = 18340300`.

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Perfect, Union helped me to connect those values and get all the ID's of the values I needed to get. Thank you. :)